# Working With Units in ML (SML/NJ)

Tags: smlnj, ml

I am trying to make a function that will print binary trees. My binary tree datatype looks like this:

```
    datatype 'a BT = empty | bTree of 'a * 'a BT * 'a BT;
```

I have also made a function that prints integers, which I will be using for the nodes:

```
    fun printInt n = print (Int.toString n);
```

As you can see, the BT datatype has 3 nodes ('a,'a BT, 'a BT), I have started making a displayTree function, but cannot find a way to print out the unit types that my printInt function returns. I'm sure that there are other ways to do this, but in this case, how would I return three concatenated unit types. Here is what I have so far (I understand that the @s are incorrect).

```
    fun displayTree T =
let
    val bTree (root, left, right) = T;
in
    (printInt root)@ (displayTree left) @ (displayTree right)
end;
```

I am not worried about the line formatting of the trees yet. I am just unsure of how to append my (printInt root) to the recursive calls.

EDIT:

I want the displayTree function to be polymorphic

Answer (score 1):

You have to make few changes in order to get this code working:

Change tree definition to:

```
datatype btree =
                 Empty |
                 Node of int * btree * btree;
```

`printInt` function is to short, so I will avoid it in this case:

```
fun displayTree T = 
    case T of 
        Empty               => ""
       |Node(root, left, right) => (Int.toString root) ^ (displayTree left) ^ (displayTree right)
```

Note that this function returns string that represents tree, so you can print it when needed. String concatenation is represented by `@`. And the secret ingredient that you was missing in your function is called "pattern matching". In this case you can avoid pattern matching with if statement.

Let's make a polymorphic type first:

```
datatype 'a btree =
                 Empty |
                 Node of 'a * 'a btree * 'a btree
```

Let's make this function polymorphic:

```
fun displayTree T f = 
    case T of 
        Empty               => ""
       |Node(root, left, right) => (f root) ^ (displayTree left f ) ^ (displayTree right f )
```

Now you have to define function f that converts your anonymous type to a `string`.

Let's go a step further and define same function that returns a list of node values that you can print:

```
fun displayTree T f = 
    case T of 
        Empty               => [""]
       |Node(root, left, right) => [f root] @ (displayTree left f) @ (displayTree right f)
```

And you can turn this to return list a of `unit`s:

```
fun displayTree T f = 
    case T of 
        Empty               => [print ""]
       |Node(root, left, right) => [print(f root)] @ displayTree left f @ displayTree right f
```

but I don't understand what are you going to do with them.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my `displayTree` function will be polymorphic. I was just showing one type in this example. And string concatenation is `^`, `@` is for lists.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code so it's difficult to know where to start.  If you want *printInt* to actually print the value of the node and return *unit* then you don't want to do anything with the result.  You should simply discard it and the calls should look like

```
(printInt root; displayTree left; displayTree right)
```

You may not need the parentheses inside the *let..in..end* block but you need the semicolons.

Other problems are that you need to pattern match on the tree.  Also by including *printInt* in the body of *displayTree* you are only able to print values of type *int bTree*.  If you want *displayTree* to be polymorphic you need to pass in a function to print the node since it will depend on the type of the node.  The function you pass in could be *printInt* if the node is an integer but something else for a node of a different type.